# Why Form is not saving the many to many field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, python-3.5

The problem with the code is that the form is sucessfully getting passed but the model is not saving the many to many field in the Profile models.
All the values are getting saved except the food and type.
Please help me with the code.
Model

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length =30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class Food(models.Model):
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_name

class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

class Type(models.Model):
    types = models.CharField(max_length =80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.types

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = image_upload_to)
    city = models.OneToOneField(City)
    fav_food = models.ManyToManyField(Food)
    relationship = models.OneToOneField(Relationship)
    preferrs = models.ManyToManyField(Type)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('chatbot')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_username()
`
```

And my Model form is as follow

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields = ['avatar','city','fav_food','relationship','preferrs']
```

and my view is as follow

```
def ProfileCreate(request):
    template="profile.html"
    context={}
    if request.user.get_username()=='':
        return redirect('account_login')
    if Profile.objects.all().filter(user__username=request.user.get_username()).count()>0:
        return redirect('chatbot')
    else:

        form = ProfileForm(request.POST ,request.FILES or None)

        if form.is_valid():

            new_profile = form.save(commit=False)

            user = User.objects.all().filter(username=request.user.get_username())[0]
            new_profile.user=user
            new_profile.save()
            return redirect('chatbot')

        context['form']=form


    return render(request,template,context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are saving the form with `commit=False`, you must call the form's `save_m2m` method after saving the instance.

```
new_profile = form.save(commit=False)
# no need to fetch the user here, just use request.user
new_profile.user = request.user
new_profile.save()
form.save_m2m()
```

See the docs on the [model form save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more info.

Comment: thanks , and instead of new_profile.save_m2m() it will be form.save_m2m()